# Calculate with arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Hello how can i calculate with this array i want to calculate the difference of two arrays frist array

```
$neu = Array ( [1] => 0 [1.5] => 0 [1.75] => 0 [1.95] => 0 [2.1] => 0 [2.45] => 0 [2.8] => 0 [3.95] => 0 [4.95] => 10)

$rueck = Array ( [1] => 0 [1.5] => 0 [1.75] => 0 [1.95] => 0 [2.1] => 0 [2.45] => 0 [2.8] => 0 [3.95] => 0 [4.95] => 5)
```

and the result should look like this

```
$result = Array ( [1] => 0 [1.5] => 0 [1.75] => 0 [1.95] => 0 [2.1] => 0 [2.45] => 0 [2.8] => 0 [3.95] => 0 [4.95] => 5)
```

what i want to have foreach key calculate like this $new - $rueck = $result

//edit

my solution (doesnt work)

```
foreach($this->neu as $price=>$value){
    foreach($this->rueck as $priceold=>$valueold){
        $result = $value - $valueold;
    }
    $this->calcresult += array($price=>$result);
}
```

Comment: foreach loop, maths, what have you tried?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: you dont want 2 loops, just one, use the key from the first array inside the loop to access the 2nd array

Comment: Slightly Odd keys you have there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$neu = [ '1' => 0, '1.5' => 0, '1.75' => 0, '1.95' => 0, '2.1' => 0, '2.45' => 0, '2.8' => 0, '3.95' => 0, '4.95' => 10];
$rueck = [ '1' => 0, '1.5' => 0, '1.75' => 0, '1.95' => 0, '2.1' => 0, '2.45' => 0, '2.8' => 0, '3.95' => 0, '4.95' => 5];

$res_arr = [];

foreach($neu as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset($rueck[$key]))
    {
        $res_arr[$key] = (int)$neu[$key] - (int)$rueck[$key];
    }
}

print_r($res_arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [1.5] => 0
    [1.75] => 0
    [1.95] => 0
    [2.1] => 0
    [2.45] => 0
    [2.8] => 0
    [3.95] => 0
    [4.95] => 5
)
```